# send HTML email with bootstrap in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, html-email, bootstrap-modal

I want to send an HTML email using codeigniter. It actually works but it isn't displayed the way I want it to be displayed. I want it to look like this [image]

But it is diplayed as a plain text and a link in my email. How am I going to solve this?

Here's my code (emailhtml view):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>

            <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
        <body> 
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            Hi User,
                        </div> 
                       <div class="modal-body">
                            This is your final step to complete your registration. 
                            Please confirm your email address - just click on the button below. 
                            <a href="http://localhost/MyProject/index.php/Registration/" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm Now</a>
                        </div><!--END of modalb-->

                    </div><!--END of mod-cont-->
                </div><!--END of mod-Dia-->
            </div><!--END of row-->
        </body>
    </html>
```

And in the controller:

```
            $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'tls://smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => '*****',
            'wordwrap' => true
            );

            //load email library
            $this->load->library('email', $config);

            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

            //set email information and content
            $this->email->from('xxxx@gmail.com', 'My Name');
            $this->email->to($email);
            $this->email->subject('Confirmation for Registration');
            $this->email->message($this->load->view('admin/EmailHTML', $data,true));
            $this->email->set_mailtype('html');


            $this->email->send();
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few email clients accept links to external CSS files, in fact there are even some that don't accept embedded style sheets. ([CSS support for email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/))

Your best bet is to inline all your styles. Although a good solution, this may not be a guarantee that your styles will be accepted though as support varies from client to client (see above link). There are some inliners that might help you ([Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html) and [MailChimp](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) are supposed to be the best).

With Mobile being the new normal for HTML email views, inlining all your styles can create an issue with mobile display. To get around this, the new theory is to design for mobile first, and then use MSO conditional statements and embedded stylesheets to display on desktop clients. ([Good article on this approach](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919))